# "error: no matching function for call to ‘push_back(char [6])". How to solve the error in this code?

Tags: c++, vector

I want to store character in the vector. But it's not working when I wanted to push back the matching character.

Error is showing in this line -

```
v.push_back(arithmetic_operator[i]);
```

The whole code is -

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<char>v;

    char str[100];
    gets(str);

    char *ptr;
    ptr = strtok(str, " ");

    char arithmetic_operator[6][6] = {"+", "-", "*", "/", "%", "="};

    while(ptr !=NULL)
    {   
        // arithmetic operator
        for(int i=0; i<sizeof(arithmetic_operator); i++){
            if(strcmp(arithmetic_operator[i], ptr) == 0)
            {
                v.push_back(arithmetic_operator[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When the input is a = b + c,
expected output will be =,+

Comment: Don't use `gets`.  It was previously deprecated and has since been removed from both the C and C++ standards.

Comment: It says it in the error message that the type of what you're pushing back it `char[6]`. `v` is  a vector of `char`, however. Did you mean to push pack `arithmetic_operator[i][0]` instead (not that I'd recommend storing the operators in this 2D array construct)?

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)

Comment: `sizeof(arithmetic_operator)` is not doing what you expect it's doing. It returns size of the whole array in bytes, so in this case it returns 36.

Comment: What's your point with `sizeof(arithmetic_operator)`? with `continue;`?

Comment: Actually, I can write 6 instead of `sizeof(arithmetic_operator)` and `continue;` is used because there are more for loop in my code but I didn't mention that code in here.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
```

Just no. Never. Not even once. Don't do this, and treat any example code which shows this, with extreme caution (ideally, ignore it and find something that isn't rubbish).

```
vector<char>v;
v.push_back(...);
```

The [documentation for `push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) shows that a `vector<char>` will expect a char as the argument.

```
char arithmetic_operator[6][6] = {"+", ... };
```

but obviously `arithmetic_operator[i]` is nothing like a char. If you print the *whole* error, it might even tell you what the type really is, but as a clue, `arithmetic_operator[i][0]` *would* be a `char`.

Comment: I have a feeling the OP is going to misunderstand your clue. The correct code is `arithmetic_operator[i][0]`

Comment: Fair point, I made the clue less misleading. I still have no idea why it uses `char[6][6]` in the first place, though.

Comment: Yes, `arithmetic_operator[i][0]` is correct code. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: you are passing a `char*` to a `vector<char>`. So, defining `v` as `vector<char*>` will solve the error.

In addition, as already pointed out, `gets` is [deprecated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/gets) in C++11 and will be removed in C++14. For the same functionalities you can use `std::fgets`. Have a look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets).